# Moving a message to inbox from database

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to move a message from the application into inbox?

I have made an application that will catch a message before system inbox and make a new entry of the message in the database.

But after that i want to give an option to the user called "move to inbox"/"save to inbox" to a particular selected message.

Is it possible to do so? How?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are doing this exactly?

Comment: @Smith:
I am given a task to receive the message using broadcastReceiver and store this message in my application database.

It works fine.

Now it is asked to move the message from my application to the system inbox.
I don't know that this is possible or not?
Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with this below code?

For content://sms/inbox , fields are **_id, thread_id, address, person, date, protocol, read, status, type, reply_path_present, subject, body, service_center, locked**.

```
ContentValues values;
values.put("date",mDate);
values.put("address",mPhoneNumber);
values.put("body",mMessage);
... // put values for various fields
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),values);
```

I have not time to try it right now but it should work logically.please let me know if it doesn't!

Comment: what will be the value return in "success"?

Comment: it will be the _id of the message you have inserted into inbox.

Comment: The error is showing that type of the success should be Uri.

Any Permission is needed for writing in inbox?

Comment: I have used...

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"></uses-permission>

Comment: Include all send,recieve,write and read permissions of sms. because i dont know which particular would be required. :P

Comment: and try removing long success..just write line after "=".

Answer (score 0):

My idea is set a status to your message like 1 is new, 2=inbox, 3=draft.

So, if you want to move to inbox just change/update it's status to 2. Something like that.